# Get ViewGroup(Layout) of custom view

Tags: java, android

I made a custom View, called ColorPicker. I create my ColorPicker in my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_settings">

    <visuals.customview.ColorPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the ColorPicker's Constr i need a ref to my LinearLayout, but i can't find any answer here.

```
public ColorPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    //LinearLayout layout = ???;
}
```

I tried following solutions which i read on similar questions:

```
getParent();
```

returns null

```
getRootView();
```

returns the ColorPicker itself

```
findViewByID(R.id.linearlayout_settings);
```

returns null

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `getParent()` inside your `View`'s constructor, at that point the `View` has not been attached to the parent. If you want to get the parent and be sure it is not null, override your custom `View`'s `protected void onAttachedToWindow()`

```
public class ColorPicker extends View {

    public ColorPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();    
        // call getParent() here
    }
}
```

Comment: That's kind of obvious... Thank you very much for your help, works now :D

Answer (score -1):

Use The Color Dialog Box
This Better For pick color on Activity
  colorDialog.setPickerColor(YourActivity.this, 2, color);

OR

```
<visuals.customview.ColorPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vis1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Create Object in Java File 
find object in java file

Try it.